# Why is my Worksheet not rendering my csv data?

Tags: next.js, jspreadsheet-ce

I am using the library jspreadsheet([https://jspreadsheet.com/docs/data]). When I load a 3rd Worksheet into my Spreadsheet component, the worksheet is added. And then duplicates my entire Spreadsheet. Leading to 6 tabs instead of 3(duplicates the 3 tabs twice). I am completely stumped. Their support team said to wrap my app in Strictmode, but that didn't do anything.

When entering the CSV location from my file system, it gives me a 404, resource not found error. Is there something I am missing where you cant load CSV files from another directory in the project?

I am using Next.js environment.

[[image: Without 3rd Worksheet Component]]
[[image: With 3rd Worksheet Component]]

```
    <Spreadsheet ref={spreadsheet} license={license}>
        <Worksheet data={worksheet1.data} columns={worksheet1.columns}  minDimensions={worksheet1.minDimensions}/>
        <Worksheet data={worksheet2.data} columns={worksheet2.columns} validations={worksheet2.validations}/>
        <Worksheet csv='../../lib/FixtureCodes.csv' minDimensions={[10,1]} />
     </Spreadsheet>
      <input type="button" value="Add Fixtures"
                onClick={saveSheets} />
```

I have tried everything. I am so stumped. If anyone can offer guidance to the foundational root of my problem, I would greatly appreciate it.